# How to lower refresher below top point?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, pull-to-refresh

Is there a way to move the ionic refresher lower below the top point of the start of your `<ion-content>`? I have an expandable top toolbar, and I need to use fullscreen attribute inside of my `<ion-content>`, which makes it full screen, and hence pushes the refresher outside of the screen view. I need to somehow displace it by around 50px lower (like `top: -50px`), but I can't find the SCSS file/property which is responsible for this functionality.

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no [variable](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) for the refresh position.

The only way I found to affect it is by creating a CSS rule, in `src/app/app.scss` for example:

```
ion-refresher {
    top: 100px !important;
}
```

`!important` is required because Ionic will otherwise override it on the element itself during pulling.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this is a better way. Since I'm using a Component for shrinkable header, I'm already invoking the ion-content there. Hence when I'm doing a Dom Re-render, each time while scrolling, I'm also changing the position of my ion-content as follows:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.scrollArea._elementRef.nativeElement, 'top', (this.newHeaderHeight - 74) + 'px');
```

Where scrollArea is my ion-content gotten by ID.

This is the tutorial I've used, plus significantly improved his code for best performance (Facebook style): https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-shrinking-header-for-segments-in-ionic/